# Alternatives to QProcess::startDetached() and QProcess start() as they are deprecated

Tags: qt, qprocess

What are the alternatives to `QProcess::startDetached()` and `QProcess::start()` to start an external application as they are marked deprecated in qt5?

Comment: Can you show me where the docs say they are deprecated? I don't see that [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#start).

Comment: @JarMan, that is the issue. When I write these functions on Qt Creator using qt5, I see the deprecated warning. But these are not mentioned on the docs above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only some overloads of the `start()` and `startDetached()` method are deprecated like:

- [`void start(const QString &command, QIODevice::OpenMode mode = ReadWrite)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess-obsolete.html#start-1)
- [`bool startDetached(const QString &command)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess-obsolete.html#startDetached-2)

But the others are still available:

- [`void QProcess::start(const QString &program, const QStringList &arguments, QIODevice::OpenMode mode = ReadWrite)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#start)
- [`void QProcess::start(QIODevice::OpenMode mode = ReadWrite)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#start-2)
- [`bool QProcess::startDetached(qint64 *pid = nullptr)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#startDetached)
- [`bool QProcess::startDetached(const QString &program, const QStringList &arguments, const QString &workingDirectory = QString(), qint64 *pid = nullptr)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#startDetached-1)