# What is the correct way to execute a CMD command with QProcess to get the output as QString?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm new using QT, I need to execute a CMD command on windows and get the output of this command as a string to later process and get specific data. The following code works well (it seems to work well). The only problem is that I get the following warning: `"start is deprecated"`, I think this warning message is because the `start` method needs an `arguments` list as parameter.

```
QString command = "tasklist /FI \"IMAGENAME eq notepad.exe\"";
QProcess *executeCommand = new QProcess();
executeCommand->start(command);
executeCommand->waitForFinished(-1);
QString output = executeCommand->readAllStandardOutput();
executeCommand->terminate();
qDebug() << commandOutput;
```

how can I remove this warning message?

Also I found in the web that I can use `system()` to execute a CMD command, but I'm not able to catch the output as string.

Another question: which of the above options is better to achieve what I'm trying to do, the QProcess or System (if is possible to get the output as QString)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [read QProcess output to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17344807/read-qprocess-output-to-string)

Comment: No, sorry, I need to suppress the warning message, I think I'm using the `start` method in the wrong way.

Comment: @BadRobot Try separating arguments from the command and passing them as an optional `QStringList` parameter to [QProcess::start](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qprocess.html#start) either manually like `executeCommand->start("tasklist", {"/FI", "IMAGENAME eq notepad.exe"});` or use [QProcess::splitCommand](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qprocess.html#splitCommand) to generate the argument list (excluding the command itself, of course).

Comment: @absolute.madness. Hi, a few minutes ago before you answer me, I try with a line of code similar than yours and works perfect. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @BadRobot also you don't need to call `QProcess::terminate`. Especially after using `waitForFinished` but even without it the child process will be killed by [QProcess::~QProcess](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qprocess.html#dtor.QProcess) when needed.

Comment: @absolute.madness, thanks I'll remove that code line.

Answer (score 1):

There is an answer [read QProcess output to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17344807/read-qprocess-output-to-string) recommending static method `QProcess::readAllStandardOutput()` returning `QByteArray`. Then just instantiate `QString` from `QByteArray` implicitly.

If you are working on Qt application, it is better to stay inside Qt API to keep the code more or less portable.

Comment: Hi Andrei, yes, in fact with the code above I can obtain the output of the CMD command and works well. I'm using QProcess to execute the command, but the only issue is I get a warning message: `start` is deprecated

Comment: Hi! There is an answer pointing out this problem. https://stackoverflow.com/a/69165867/9560245 The only deprecation is declared for methods accepting full command strings without additional mode selectors.